# Spring Boot Web Flux and Flutter

Tags: flutter

is there anyone using spring boot web flux with flutter for real time database? I can't found any documentation.Anybody know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a little solution that for me works, but I don't know if it is the best way to implement this.

Imagine a server side function like :

```
@GetMapping("/elems")
public Flux<Elem> getelems(){
    return elemReactiveRepository.findAll();
}
```

from client side we can receive it as a stream

```
   import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

   Stream<http.Response> getelems()  {
   String url= "http://IPADDRESS/elems";
   final response = http.get(url).asStream();
   return response;
   }
```

And then a graphic element that can read the stream could be :

```
  StreamBuilder(

      stream: getelems(),

        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white),
              ),
            );
          } else {
            List<Elem> list = jsonaslist(snapshot.data);
            return ListView.builder(
     //         padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => buildItem(context, list, index),
              itemCount: list.length,
            );
          }
        },)

***********

List<Elem> jsonaslist(http.Response data){
final risultato = json.decode(data.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
return risultato.map<Elem>((json) => 
Elem.fromJson(json)).toList();
}
```

Where Elem.fromJson is a function that builds the object given a json string. There are autogeneration tools for it.

If there is something to improve this kind of solution, grateful. I need it.
Hope this helps.

Comment: It is not working if i consume Stream Data.For example it is my controller.I can't receive data from flutter side.
`    @GetMapping(value = "/streamItem", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE)
    public Flux<ItemCapped> getItemsStream(){
        return itemReactiveCappedRepository.findItemsBy();
    }`